# Im trying to make a shooter game with pygame but it makes an error

Tags: python, pygame

So I just started creating a shooter game but in main.py there is an error that says that there is no video device
I tried adding more code and it did not work
[Here is the link to the game](https://replit.com/@RobertGinovski/idk-1#main.py)

Comment: You have to add the code in the question. This is not a recommendation or just "nice to have". Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change.

Comment: You're missing `pygame.init()`.  Also, it's probably not possible to run from https://replit.com/.

Comment: @FiddlingBits No. You don't need to call `pygame.init`

Comment: Minimal example: https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py. (works with and without `pygame.init()`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, because you're using Replit, you need to make sure that you're using the pygame template and not a python one, a very common mistake that I used to make alot. After that you need to put `pygame.init()` after your import like this:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_height=1000
display_width=2000
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
```

or won't be able to initialize pygame modules, which will cause you another error very soon when you start to actually make your game.